# Is there a word for a person either disinterested or just doesn't partake in gossiping?

Tags: single-word-requests, diction

I swear there's a word that's essentially the opposite of a gossiper, but can't for the life of me remember what it is. I know there are words for the opposite {ie gossiper, busybody, etc...}, but where are the words for what I'm looking for?

Comment: You're asking for nouns, but here are some adjectives that work almost as well: [close-mouthed / close-lipped](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/close-mouthed).

Comment: I would say "kind", or "non-judgmental".

Answer (score 1):

I think the word you're looking for (if you want an antonym of *gossiper*) is [**confidant**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/confidant):

> one to whom secrets are entrusted; *especially* : INTIMATE · He is a trusted *confidant* of the president.

Answer (score 0):

There are many synonyms of **gossiper**, both single word and phrases.  True single word antonyms are lacking. Suggestions, both single word and phrases are:

**reticent. discreet. close-mouthed. close-lipped.** [Oxford](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/close-mouthed)

> ‘The candidates have been close-mouthed about their fund-raising
>   goals.’
>
> ‘He is notoriously close-mouthed.’